# IIS Rewrite rule for a subfolder path

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

i am hosting a couple of websites on different servers and i am using IIS 10 + url rewrite on the frontend server as a reverse proxy only.

the redirection is as follows :

- www.example.com   rewrite to server A :
- siteB.example.com rewrite to server B :
- siteC.example.com rewrite to server C :

This scheme allows me to only have one certificate to manage for all my subdomain websites

This is working fine on subdomains  with conditions matching rules.

Now i want to do a rewrite rule from a sub directory to map the entire site D to that subdirectory.

example:

- www.example.com/siteD   rewrite to server D :

the site redirects the first page but the aspect look weird and links are not functioning.

is it the right way to handle that with conditions {C:2} or should the pattern be applied to the match url ?

here is my web.config :

```
<rule name="www.example.com_site_d" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/siteD/)(.*)$" />
                    </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://myinternalsited:80/{C:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the REQUEST_URI means the entire URL path with querystring.

If the REQUEST_URI is `/siteD/test?q=IIS+url+rewrite`, the result of C:2 is:`test?q=IIS+url+rewrite`.

Result:

[image]

If the REQUEST_URI is `/siteD?q=IIS+url+rewrite`,the condition will not be matched.

Comment: i came to the same conclusion but siteD is not working as expected with rewrite  {C:2}. unlike rewrite {R:1} will work from a subdomain scheme.

I saw there is a way to do it with "Rewrite Maps" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

is this a better solution ?